# How to unselect the text of a textbox when it gets focus, when tab is pressed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a series of text boxes in a row, which are used to enter time. When the user comes back to an already edited text box, the browser highlights the text within that textbox.

1. How would I un-select the text in it when the text box gets the focus, and
2. Set the cursor to the beginning of the text within the text box?

I have tried the following ways but for no good:

In textboxfocushandler:

```
var html = $("#MyTextArea").val();
$("#MyTextArea").focus().val("").val(html);
```

Select handler for textbox:

```
if (window.getSelection) {
    if (window.getSelection().empty) {  // Chrome
        window.getSelection().empty();
    } else if (window.getSelection().removeAllRanges) {  // Firefox
        window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    }
} else if (document.selection && document.selection.empty) {  // IE?
    document.selection.empty();
}
```

Comment: [Check this, it's similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11137794/javascript-focus-remove-text-highlight/11137907#11137907).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the browser doesn't select the text until after the focus handler has executed. You could try using `setTimeout()` to delay your code, like this:

```
$('input').focus(function() {
    var $input = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
        setCaretPos($input[0], 0, 0);
    }, 0)
});
```

**[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/john_s/A2ZcT/2/)**

This uses the following method to set the caret position.

```
function setCaretPos(element, begin, end) {
    if (element.setSelectionRange) {
        element.setSelectionRange(begin, end);
    } else if (element.createTextRange) {
        var range = element.createTextRange();
        range.collapse(true);
        range.moveEnd('character', end);
        range.moveStart('character', begin);
        range.select();
    }
}
```

If you decide you want the focus at the end of the text, you can use:

```
var end = $input.val().length;
setCaretPos($input[0], end, end);
```

Credit:

I got the code for the `setCaretPos()` function from the [jQuery mask plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/). That plugin contains a `.caret()` plugin method that you could use instead.